# What does the 'Sweetness' stat do?

Tags: sugar-rush-speedway

In [Sugar Rush Speedway](http://www.disney.co.uk/wreck-it-ralph/games/?game=sugar-rush), (one of the web-based accompaniment games for the Disney movie, Wreck-it Ralph), you get to choose between most of the racers that appear in the movie.

Each racer has 3 stats, shown below:
[image: the 'Chews your Racer' screen, showing the stats for racer Taffyta]

Speed and Handling are pretty straightforward, but what does the 'Sweetness' stat do, if anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it out, and it seems the "Sweetness" stat is purely cosmetic, relating to the racer's personality, hence why Taffyta has a very low Sweetness.

Comment: I agree with this. The sweetness seems to be related to the racer's personality. However, the racers' stats in the game aren't official. Taffyta, according to her official stats, is one of two racers with a sweetness of 90%.