# What is Candy Coating and Sweetness?

Tags: sugar-rush-speedway

In Sugar Rush Speedway, a kart racing game from Wreck-it Ralph, has characters called "The Sugar Rush Racers". Each racer has four official stats: Speed, Handling, Candy Coating, and Sweetness; the browser-based version only includes Speed, Handling, and Sweetness. What is Candy Coating and Sweetness? Speed and Handling are pretty simple but do Candy Coating and Sweetness even do anything?
Here are the official stats for one of the characters.

[image]

Speed: 70%

Handling: 60%

Candy Coating: 45%

Sweetness: 50%

Comment: [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141476/what-does-the-sweetness-stat-do) talks about sweetness.

Comment: Referring to the post that @TimmyJim linked, candy coating is likely to be cosmetic too; with emphasis on the character's vehicle's appearance. However, one could argue that it's synonymous to a defense statistic, which could be tested, but, since I don't play, I can only speculate.